# ObservablePriorityQueue<T> Implementation

Tags: c#, performance, priority-queue

I have a requirement in my current project that will need a Prioritised Queue that supports the IObservable interface. Please notify me of any problems with the implementation that I currently have:

**ObservablePriorityQueue<T>**

```
public sealed class ObservablePriorityQueue<T> : IQueue<T>, IObservable<T> where T : IPrioritised
{
    #region "IObservable<T> Implementation"
    // A list of the subscribers for the IObservable implementation
    List<IObserver<T>> _subscribers = new List<IObserver<T>>(10);

    Object _observableSyncLock = new Object();

    #region "Interface specific"
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The observer cannot be null.");
        }

        if (!_subscribers.Contains(observer))
        {
            lock (_observableSyncLock)
            {
                _subscribers.Add(observer);
            }
        }

        return new Disposable(() =>
        {
            this.Unsubscribe(observer);
        });
    }
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The observer cannot be null.");
        }

        observer.OnCompleted();

        if (_subscribers.Contains(observer))
        {
            // remove the entry, but don't dispose it just 
            // in case they want to re-subscribe with the same observer later
            lock (_observableSyncLock)
            {
                _subscribers.Remove(observer);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region "IQueue<T> Implementation"

    readonly List<T> _data = new List<T>(100);
    Object _queueSyncLock = new Object();

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The item to be enqueued cannot be null");
        }

        lock (_queueSyncLock)
        {
            _data.Add(value);
        }

        // now that the entry has been added, notify everyone
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_observableSyncLock)
            {
                foreach (IObserver<T> subscriber in _subscribers)
                {
                    subscriber.OnNext(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (_data.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (_queueSyncLock)
            {
                var result = _data.OrderByDescending(element => element.Priority).ThenBy(element => element.TimeStamp).First();
                _data.Remove(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (_data.Count > 0)
        {
            return _data.OrderByDescending(element => element.Priority).ThenBy(element => element.TimeStamp).First();
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public Int32 Count { get { return _data.Count; } }
    #endregion
}
```

**IQueue<T>**

```
public interface IQueue<T>
{

    void Enqueue(T value);
    T Dequeue();
    T Peek();

    Int32 Count { get; }
}
```

**IPrioritised<T>**

```
public interface IPrioritised
{
    QueuePriority Priority { get; }
    DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
}
```

**QueuePriority**

```
public enum QueuePriority
{
    None = 0,
    Lowest = 1,
    Low = 2,
    Normal = 3,
    High = 4,
    Highest = 5
}
```

**Disposable**

```
public sealed class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    readonly Action _action;
    public Disposable(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_action != null)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. At first, I was confused what exactly did the implementation of `IObservable<T>` mean. You should properly document that.
2. You don't need to have a separate lock objects. If you're locking on a specific object, I think you should use that object in the `lock`.
3. If you're just calling a single method in your lambda, you can use more succinct syntax: `new Disposable(() => this.Unsubscribe(observer))`.
4. If you want to make your code thread-safe, you need to lock all your reads too. In `Unsubscribe()` you don't do that, which means someone could write to the list while you're reading it. The same problem is in `Peek()`.
5. `Dequeue()` shouldn't return `default(T)` if the queue is empty. This can be problematic especially with value types. Instead, you should have a method like [`bool TryDequeue(out T result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208.aspx).
6. You're accessing `Count` outside of a lock. I wouldn't rely on the fact that doing this is safe, I think you should `lock` before accessing it too.
7. Since you're using Rx, you might as well use their [`Disposable.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable.create%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) instead of creating your own.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will review these and fix accordingly. As a note, I am not using Rx everything is out of the BCL.

Comment: I have confirmed the need for seperate locks here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813780/multiple-lock-objects-necessary

Comment: @StuartBlackler Well, I think `IObservable<T>` is much less useful without Rx, so you might consider using it.

Comment: @StuartBlackler And you really don't need the separate lock objects, I have added my own answer to that SO question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to svick's points, I noticed that in your `Enqueue` method you're checking queued values for `null`:

```
public void Enqueue(T value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The item to be enqueued cannot be null");
    }
```

However, there is no constraint on the generic type, `T`. If the user intends to queue value types (such as structs), this will fail.